# Translate Quicklaunch bar

Tags: 2010, term-store

This is totally new for me, so it is possible that I am completely on the wrong track.

I was asked to translate the portal to dutch, meaning that the user would like to see "Klanten" instead of "Customers" in the left navigation. My research on this topic lead me to the `Term Store`.

So, dutch language pack installed, I created a new group, with one item, "Customers" and set the Dutch value.

What is not clear from here is how can I use this translation?

Comment: have you tired to set the language settings of the site to Dutch?

Comment: Yes, I changed the language, but I didn't see any difference. The standard links like the "recycle bin" and "all site content" are translated, but not the rest in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, even if it's not the "cleanest" way to do it, it's how I have dealt with this so far.

We have 2 languages in our SharePoint, english and french. To translate a navigation link to french, I simply login with a french account which has the rights to edit the link (I have an admin account which I set the language to french for this purpose), and edit the link title. So, a french user will see the french title, and an English user will see the English title.

I'm not sure where the information is stocked, and I'm sure there is another solution out there but didn't got time to search for it yet. I'd be glad to learn the best solution also.